# Can I load a Spring contextConfigLocation from a blob in my database?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

The idea here is to load some xml from the database to use, but I need it to be a bean that loads once at startup. The xml absolutely has to be in the database.

I apologize if this is a duplicate, but I cannot find anything that details this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All spring beans by default are `singleton` unless specified otherwise in the `scope`. So when your application is deployed it will be loaded at that point.

```
 <!-- bean that uses the loaded XML configs from the db --> 
 <bean id="someDAO" class="myPackage.SomeDAO">
        <property name="configLoader">
            <ref local="configLoader"/>
        </property>
 </bean>
 <!-- bean that loads the XML data from the database -->
 <bean id="configLoader" class="myPackage.ConfigLoader" />
```

Comment: I realize this, but I want to load a bean that is defined in a blob in the database. I guess my question is more along the lines of how to configure web.xml to pull it in as a regular context file.

Comment: So basically - you want to load the context xml file itself from a table?

Comment: thanks for the help. that's close enough to what i was looking for.